# Google Analytics - Logging Campaign Information?

Tags: google-analytics

I have created a unique URL (http://www.example.com/uniqueurl) and used the Google Link Builder to create a campaign for this page.

So basically, people see this unique URL at trade shows and on print ads, they can visit that URL and they will be redirected to www.example.com/uniqueurl+campaign-characters-medium-etc which will take them to my home page, but also log the source, medium etc.

The home page has a Google Analytics code on it, however I'm not seeing any information regarding these campaign settings inside analytics.... am I missing something? Am I looking in the wrong place? Does the 302 redirect page need an Analytics code on it as well?

Thanks in advance.

Code as follows:

On the PHP redirect page (www.example.com/uniqueurl):

```
<?

    Header( "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently" );

    Header( "Location: http://example.com/more-example.php?utm_source=WA15&utm_medium=offline&utm_campaign=WA15" );

?>
```

And on the actual page (the Google Analytics code):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

      var _gaq = _gaq || [];
      _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-1234567-1']);
      _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

     (function() {
        var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
      })();

</script>
```

Comment: The campaign parameters need to get to the page where your analytics code is - if they are included in the redirect campaign tracking should work fine. Without seeing the actual format of the link you use (your example does not contain any parameters) it's hard to tell.

Comment: I have added the code from both the redirect and the home page.

Comment: Hm, looks good - in fact if I insert my own domain name in the redirect I see the campaign info show up in realtime view. When you visit your redirect page yourself, do you see the parameters in the redirected url (there might be another redirect at example.com that removes the parameters) ? As for "am I looking in the wrong place", where exactly are you looking and since when (campaign reports might take a few hours or a day to catch up) ?

Comment: I can see the parameters are still in the URL of the page I'm directing it to. It redirects fine, all seems good and well? I am looking in both Acquisition>Campaign (do I need to set anything in here? I'm not completely analytics savvy) and I've also been watching in realtime?

Comment: You should be looking in Traffic Sources and then sort by Source! @user3737700